# How to add button using javascript in html page dynamically

Tags: javascript

I want to add button on HTML page dynamically using java-script. Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Can you put a little more effort into your question? Show us what you've tried, where you got stuck, etc.

Comment: Its up to _you_ to do some effort, this is not a do-it-for-you service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var button = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "button";

var whatever;//get whatever you want to append button to

whatever.appendChild(button);
```

Just create your button and add it to whatever dom element you want to using appendChild...